# Weird appearance when append item in generator to list in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to generate a p-level pascal triangle using the code below:

```
def triangles(p):
    L = [1]
    count = 0
    while count < p:
        yield L
        L.append(0)
        L = [L[i - 1] + L[i] for i in range(len(L))]
        count = count + 1
def pascal(p):
    result = []
    t = triangles(p)
    for i in range(p):
        result.append(next(t))
    return result
```

The expected result of pascal(5) should be [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]], but I got [[1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3, 3, 1, 0], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0]] instead.

I tried to print each i in triangles(5),

```
for i in triangles(5):
    print i
```

and the result is:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Then I tried:

```
result = []
for i in triangles(5):
    print result
    print i
    result.append(i)
    print result
```

And the output looks like:

```
[] # result in step 1, before append
[1] # 1st item in triangles(5)
[[1]] # result in step 1, after append
[[1, 0]] # result in step 2, before append, here's where it changes
[1, 1]
[[1, 0], [1, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
[1, 2, 1]
[[1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0]]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[[1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3, 3, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3, 3, 1, 0]]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[[1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3, 3, 1, 0], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

Why append will change the previous value in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.append(0)` changes the list after you've yielded it, because objects in python are shared.

Try

```
L = L + [0]
```

instead, to create a new list instead of changing it in-place.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this by change result.append(next(t)) to result.append(list(next(t)))